# How to turn queries to perform efficiently in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, query-optimization

Consider i have a 15 categories and 6 sub-categories and i have table items where i have set of records where i have to fetch in the following manner

```
category 1 ---> level 1 ---> 3 items with maximum price
category 1 ---> level 2 ---> 3 items with maximum price
  ...
  ...
  ...
category 15 ---> level 6 ---> 3 items with maximum price
```

and

```
@categories.each do |value|
   @sub-categories.each do |value1|
      array = Item.find(:all, :conditions => ["customer_id IN (?) AND category_id = ? AND sub-category_id = ?", @customer, value.id, value1.id], :order => 'price DESC', :limit => 3)
            array.each do |value2|
                   @max_price_item_of_each_customer << value2
            end
          end
        end
```

but this would take much time as this iterates. So how can i change this in such a way the time can be reduced? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what a Category, Level and item could be? I'm having a hard time understanding your data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all depends on the scale of records you're working with, but if you're working with a reasonable set, this should be faster and will reduce your queries to 1.

```
@customer_id = 1
@categories  = [1, 2, 3]
@subs        = [4, 5, 6]

@max_price_item_of_each_customer = []
items = Item.where(customer_id: @customer, category_id: @categories, subcategory_id: @subcategories)
items.group_by{|item| item.category_id}.each_pair do |category_id, category_items|
  category_items.group_by{|item| item.subcategory_id}.each_pair do |subcategory_id, subcategory_items|
    @max_price_item_of_each_customer += subcategory_items.sort{|x, y| y.price <=> x.price }.first(3)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thankyou and this worked for me with a small edit. You have missed the equals sign after "@max_price_item_of_each_customer +" which i tried editing but i could not as it is the only change.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
@max_price_item_of_each_customer = []
@categories.each do |value|   
      @max_price_item_of_each_customer +=  Item.find(:all, :conditions => ["customer_id IN (?) AND category_id = ? AND sub-category_id in (?)", @customer, value.id, @sub-categories.map(&:id)], :order => 'price DESC', :limit => 3)            
end
```

Comment: I will try this. But before that could you please tell me how will this fetch 3 items from each sub-categories. I think this would fetch 3 items for each categories.

Comment: I have tried and it picks 3 items for each category and not for each sub-category.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below might work if you use Postgresql.

1. Select a group of 3 item ids from `items` table, sorted by `price` descending and grouped by `category_id` and `subcategory_id`. You can use Postgres `array_agg` to collect the item ids after grouping.
2. Select items row, where the item ids are in those grouped item ids. After that, order the result by `category_id` ascending, `subcategory_id` ascending, and `price` descending

The result is `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so you can iterate the items as usual. Since the result is flattened (but already ordered by categories, subcategories, and price), you need to separate the different categories and subcategories yourself.

```
grouped_item_ids = Item.where(customer_id: customer_id).
  select("items.category_id, items.subcategory_id, (array_agg(items.id order by items.price desc))[1:3] AS item_ids").
  group("items.category_id, items.subcategory_id").map {|item| item["item_ids"]}
@items = Item.where(id: grouped_item_ids.flatten).
  order("items.category_id ASC, items.subcategory_id ASC, items.price desc")
```

Answer (score 1):

Following query works for me

```
   @max_price_item_of_each_customer =Item.find_by_sql(["SELECT i1.* FROM item i1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN item i2 ON (i1.category_id = i2.category_id AND i1.sub-category_id = i2.sub-category_id AND i1.id < i2.id)
      WHERE i1.customer_id IN (?) AND i1.category_id IN (?)
      GROUP BY i1.id HAVING COUNT(*) < 3
      ORDER BY price DESC", @customer, @categories.map(&:id)])
```